# How can i edit/change an existing sqoop job

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

How can i edit/change an existing sqoop job ?
Can't find any documentation related to editing of an existing sqoop job.
Please assist.

Answer (score 2):

sqoop1 document does not edit this one Job, but sqoop2 can be modified.
If sqoop1, you should

```
bin/sqoop job --show your-sync-job
```

Remember Configuration Item

```
bin/sqoop job --delete your-sync-job
```

then

```
sqoop job --create sqooptest -- import --connect jdbc:mysql://10.10.209.224:3306/sqoop --table userinfo --username sqoop --password "1234" --incremental append --check-column id --last-value 1 --fields-terminated-by '$' --target-dir '/sqoop/userinfo/import2hdfs1'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to first delete the job and then create the job agan.

Caution: `sqoop job --delete jobname` will also delete the metastore information of the job, so be carefull while doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created a sqoop job, you can always override its parameters in the next execution of that job

For example you can create a generic job like so

```
sqoop job --create hiveLoad --meta-connect jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://10.113.57.47:16000/sqoop -- import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:prasads@10.113.59.5:1521/ora11g --username user -P --table DATABASE.TABLE --incremental append --check-column COL_VALUE --last-value '300' -m 1 --target-dir '/user/somewhere' --append
```

And while executing hiveLoad, you can execute it like so

```
sqoop job --exec hiveLoad --meta-connect jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://10.113.57.47:16000/sqoop -- --username <username> --password <password> --table <database>.<table> --incremental append --check-column <column> --target-dir '/path/to/hdfs'
```

where you replace values in <> with your intended values.

However changing the definition of an existing sqoop job is not possible. The overriding facility mitigates this I believe.

The sqoop job will take the configuration of the rest of the unspecified values from the original definition.

Check out Apache Sqoop Cookbook. Its a great resource and covers almost all possible use cases.

Answer (score -1):

sqoop does not provide any edit option. You should delete job and create job as your requirements